# using a class to make an object

Tags: java, class

We have code from a while ago of the following (this is Java):

```
protected <T> T click(String buttonDescription, WebElement button, Class<T> proxy) {
    click(buttonDescription, button);
    return getPage(proxy);
}
```

You can call `click()` with a third parameter like `AnyClass.class` (where it can be any class).  The `Class<T>` proxy will hold that class.

I want to make a similar method, except `proxy` will be an array of classes. 
The new method will then call a series of methods, of different types, and the `proxy` array will show the type for each method.

For instance say "method0" is integer.  Then `proxy[0]` should be `Integer.class`. So how can I say something like `(proxy[0]'Class) x = method0();` ?

To summarize, can I pass an array of classes to a method, and how do I declare an object of each class passed in?  I won't need to do a `new` since I will be calling a method.

Comment: wooat ? do you need a `List<Class<T>> proxies` or `Class<T>[] proxies` ? *So proxy[0] would be Integer.class. so how can I say something like (proxy[0]'Class) x = method0();* , this will be the same as you were doing in `getPage(proxy)`. Maybe you should Consider passing a custom interface instead of `Class<T>`

Comment: Which ever is easiest.  I think they will both work

Comment: Do you plan to return all of these created objects at once as you do in your example? Are all of the classes you plan to use subclasses of some superclass or are they all random (`Integer`, `String`, `MyClass`, etc)?

Comment: after I entered the question I did realize they do all extend (various levels) a super class.  I could just usde that superclass, but each subclass has specific waits to know when the page has loaded so it would be better to use those.  And I should mention that all the classes will be classes for a page object.

Comment: Not sure how much detail I can go into for company confidentiality stuff.  Basically, each class will represent a web page.  Each web page has breadcrumbs or train stops (this is a line of pages you have visited so you can click on one of the train stops and go back to a previous page you viewed.  Sort of like amazon where first you are at the description page, then you go to the order page, then to your cart, and instead of clicking the back button you click a breadcrumb to say go back to the order page from your cart).  Each train stop is a different web page, but I can't hard code them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously think there should be a better way to handle breadcrumbs for your app, but to answer your question...

Here's a method which takes a `List` of classes and calls `getPage` for each class, returning a `List` of objects that were returned by `getPage`:

```
protected <T> List<T> click(String buttonDescription, WebElement button, List<Class<? extends T>> proxies) {
    click(buttonDescription, button);
    List<T> retObjs = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Class<? extends T> proxy : proxies) {
        T obj = getPage(proxy);
        if(obj!=null)
            retObjs.add(obj);
    }
    return retObjs;
}
```

You could also take in an array of `Class`es instead of a `List`, but this will give you a generic array warning every time you call it.

If you wanted to call different methods for different classes, you might need to create a select (`if`) chain to determine what to do:

```
if(Page.class.isAssignableFrom(proxy) { //true if proxy is Page or subclass of Page
    obj = getPage(proxy);
}
else if(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(proxy) {
    obj = doSomeMaths(proxy);
}
```

When you call this method, the return type `T` will be determined by the upper-bound of the inner generic of `proxies`:

```
List<Class<? extends Number>> list = new ArrayList<>();
...//Add stuff
List<Number> randoms = p.click(myString, myElement, list);

List<Class<? extends Page>> pages = new ArrayList<>();
...//Get the breadcrumbs
List<Page> crumbs = p.click(myString, myElement, pages);
```

It's not often I work with generics with such complexity, so I'd appreciate any feedback on this solution.

I'm not sure if this is the solution you're looking for. Even if it is, I recommend you carefully review your current structure and see if there is a cleaner way of handling page history/breadcrumbs.